# Laravel-dompdf (0.4) does not display remote images

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I use laravel Dompdf *(i.e. "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*")* to generate pdf file. I reference image in HTML as:

```
<img src="http://images.forbes.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg" />
```

However when I generate PDF file, it tooks a while and gives me following error:
[image]

I set  "**DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE**" option to **TRUE**. However it did not make any change.

Can you please help me.

Comment: does the process running dompdf have read/write access to the directory specified by the `DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR` configuration constant?

Comment: The same problem. And looks, it doesn't fix. You can try to use relative path to needed image. For example `media/lists/google.jpg`